# 'eslint' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm, command-line, eslint

I'm trying to install eslint & run it in vs code.  I ran this command:

```
npm i -g eslint
```

and it seemed to work, but I keep getting an error when I try to run
eslint :

"'eslint' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file".

What gives?

http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface

http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started

Comment: Use `npm ls -g` to get the location where your globals are being installed, then make sure that is in your `PATH`.  On Windows, at least, that's a semi-common issue when first getting things setup...

Comment: Can you give more details about your system? If you run `npm i -g eslint` again does it give any errors?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

The `eslint` module must **not** be installed into global.

instead, you should install `eslint-cli` module into global.

So, first install **eslint-cli** gloablly:

```
npm -g i eslint-cli
```

then in the project folder: install **eslint** locally

```
npm i eslint --save-dev
```

Then in the project folder you can run someting like: (on Windows)

```
eslint .\
```

Comment: Why is it not working with npm install --save-dev eslint-cli and it requires a global installation? Other libararies like nodemon can be used from console if they are dev dependencies.

Comment: This answer is obsolete. According to the author of `eslint-cli` :
[⚠️ This package is no longer necessary. Use the built-in npx command instead.](https://github.com/eslint/eslint-cli#readme).

Comment: Some of us has to maintain old applications and we need eslint-cli. It was enough for me to run "npm i eslint --save-dev" and not install the eslint-cli package globally.

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/getting-started#manual-set-up

Answer (score 31):

Well, if you are a Windows user and installing `eslint-cli` is not working for you, try :

```
node node_modules\eslint\bin\eslint.js --help
```

Or, you can use **npx** which lets you run local commands in `node_modules/.bin` :

```
npx eslint --help
```

For **yarn** use :

```
yarn eslint --help
```

Note:

1. This answer is updated to include `yarn` and `npx`.
2. This issue is related to modules installed *locally*.

Comment: Good one this solved my problem but one thing you missed...back slashes wouldnt work in windows cmd or gitbash as directory instead acts as an escape character, so instead use forward slashes, I'll just edit your answer if you don't mind.

Comment: Nope, it is the suitable form for windows cmd

Comment: Back slashes are correct for the Windows `cmd` terminal. If you are running the command inside [GitBash (for Windows)](https://gitforwindows.org/) then use forward slashes.

Answer (score 5):

It was the same error for me

I resolved this issue by using the below command :

- npm -g i eslint-cli
- npm i eslint-plugin-promise@latest --save-dev

Answer (score 4):

Solution posted works for me:
Step 1:
eslint install globally
npm -g i eslint-cli

Step 2:
eslint install locally
npm i eslint --save-dev

adding 2 more step:
Step 3:
eslint --init

It ask various questions e.g.
√ How would you like to use ESLint? · style
√ What type of modules does your project use? · none
√ Which framework does your project use? · none
√ Does your project use TypeScript? · No / Yes
√ Where does your code run? · browser
√ How would you like to define a style for your project? · prompt
√ What format do you want your config file to be in? · JavaScript
√ What style of indentation do you use? · tab
√ What quotes do you use for strings? · single
√ What line endings do you use? · unix
√ Do you require semicolons? · No / Yes

Answer them based on your need.

Step 4:
eslint yourfile.js
This will show errors/warnings with your file. This way linting process is completed for js file.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows users

**Add this to your Environment Path:** "`%AppData%\npm`"

[image]

Comment: What should the the key be though?