# 'eslint' is not working with the file name

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, eslint

I have tried using 
['eslint' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705440/eslint-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

And have successfully created **.eslintrc.json**

and the output of file is

`{
    "extends": "google"
}`

**But while running cmd** `eslint app.js`, it is giving me an error

`'eslint' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file`

Also I tried running command `"./node_modules/.bin/eslint app.js"` in the folder 
but it is giving me error 
`"'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file"`

System Info
PC: WINDOWS

**How to resolve this?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['eslint' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705440/eslint-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: Yes but i tried with the solution given on that question, but it still not working for me   @melpomene

Comment: How did you install `eslint`? Is it in your `package.json` or did you install it globally with `npm install -g eslint`?

Comment: I installed it globally as well as `node node_modules\eslint\bin\eslint.js --init` @btmills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, but don't know why this happens to me.

**Solution:**

I added the **script** in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "set DEBUG=* & node app.js",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint app.js"
 }
```

and run command `npm run lint` in terminal and it **start working**.

**Hope it will work for others also, who get the same error**

Comment: That solved the problem as i have added

script: { 
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint app.js"
}

Comment: `npm run lint` might but does `eslint`

Answer (score 0):

my eslintrc file is just

```
.eslintrc
```

without the .json

env = vs code with eslint rc installed globally