# 'eslint' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, eslint, npm-scripts

```
'eslint' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SURAJ SURESH\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-21T14_17_08_699Z-debug.log
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm --prefix "C:\Users\SURAJ SURESH\Desktop\firecast\functions" run lint ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\SURAJ SURESH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\SURAJ SURESH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\SURAJ SURESH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\SURAJ SURESH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

This is the first time I am using firbase functions. I tried deploying the functions and this happened. I tried editing the firebase.json file from

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  }
}
```

to

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint"
    ]
  }
}
```

But nothing worked. I was just following the firecast tutorial to get started with firebase cloud functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['eslint' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705440/eslint-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is happening because within your `firebase.json` you're trying to *use the eslint module and you don't have this module installed*.

I.e.: `"npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint"`

Maybe you could try installing the necessary eslint library and associated CLI for eslint:

```
npm i --save-dev eslint
npm install -g eslint-cli
```

**Note**: the cli must be installed globally and the eslint module should be installed locally. [Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-cli)

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked well when i uninstalled node, reinstalled it and completed the processes once again from scratch.